# How to display a GTK-widget on top of FigureCanvas in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I want to display a button (and other GTK widgets) on top of a matplotlib plot. However it is always displayed below the FigureCanvas.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import gtk
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas

win=gtk.Window()
fixed=gtk.Fixed()
win.add(fixed)

fig=mpl.figure.Figure()
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
canvas.set_size_request(100,100)
fixed.put(canvas,0,0)
button=gtk.Button('test')
fixed.put(button,80,80)
button2=gtk.Button('test2')
fixed.put(button2,0,0)

win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

I have also tried to change the z-order of the GDK window with `button.window.raise_()`, but without success.

Any way to fix this?

**EDIT**:
Turns out `gtk.Button` does not create a new GDK window but reuses its parent's window, whereas FigureCanvas does create a new one.

So if I put `button2` from above into a `gtk.EventBox`, the button is displayed above the canvas. However, it has an ugly rectangular border. Any idea how to remove it?

Comment: why do you want to put the button _on_ the canvas? Is next to it a reasonable compromise?

Comment: The plot is supposed to fill the whole screen and I want to display other widgets as temporary overlays on top of it, e.g a FileChooser to open files. If it's not possible, yes I will have to look for alternatives.

Comment: Use GTK 3 and `Gtk.Overlay`.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem in recenct days and get a good solution.

add the following line after canvas.set_size_request method.

canvas.set_has_window(False)

The reason is that default FigureCanvas object has its own window, which makes it be drawn separately. So that it will not follow the same processing order of gtk.Fixed and its other children. [Here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-drawing-model.html) is the reference on gtk's drawing model.

set_has_window method force the canvas using the same window with its parent, in order that canvas has to follow the rule gtk.Fixed specified.